# Issue with CORS while uploading images to Cloudinary from React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, cloudinary

I'm encountering a CORS-related issue while trying to upload images to Cloudinary from my React application running on http://localhost:5173. I have configured CORS on Cloudinary, included the necessary headers in my fetch request, and checked my Cloudinary account settings. However, I'm still facing the following error:

Access to fetch at 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloud_name>/image/upload' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

```
  const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('upload_preset',"<upload_preset>")
    const handleImageUpload = async () => {
        try {
            const formData = new FormData();
    
            // Populate formData with images
            for (const image of images) {
                formData.append('file', image); // 'file' is a common parameter name for image uploads
            }
    
            // Cloudinary upload endpoint
            const cloudinaryUploadUrl = 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloud_name>/image/upload';
    
            // Fetch request
            const response = await fetch(cloudinaryUploadUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                credentials:'include',
                body: formData,
                headers: {
                    
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer CLOUDINARY_key', // Replace with your Cloudinary API key
                },
            });
    
            // Check the response
            console.log(response);
    
            if (response.ok) {
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log(data);
            } else {
                // Handle error response
                console.error('Error uploading images:', response.statusText);
            }
    
        } catch (error) {
            // Handle other errors
            console.error('Error uploading images:', error);
        }
    };
```

I have ensured that the Cloudinary API key is set in the 'Authorization' header and that the credentials mode is set to 'include'.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can provide insights into resolving this CORS problem when uploading images to Cloudinary from a React application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authentication for requests to the [Upload API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference) (which you are using based on the [endpoint you're trying to call](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload)) is done via [authentication signatures](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/authentication_signatures) and not via `Authorization` (which is used with the [Admin API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api)). Therefore, you will want to remove the `Authorization` header. In addition, you will want to remove `credentials:'include',` from your request as well.

Since you're trying to use [unsigned uploads](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#unsigned_upload_syntax) (i.e. just with an upload preset) you won't need to generate a signature.

Also, your `formData` is being overwritten inside `handleImageUpload` and the value for `upload_preset` is lost. You will want to move the `formData.append('upload_preset', ...)` inside the `handleImageUpload` and ensure the `file` and `upload_preset` parameters are sent with your request to Cloudinary. You can do this by inspecting the browser's network tab as you send the request.